# How to cycle image sprite in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am looking to create characters in a game using pygame and python version 2.7.6.  I have a simple python script which allows me to create a window and print an image to the screen.  This works successfully, however it is simply a static image.

```
import pygame


class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):

        #load first sprite to image for blit"
        image = pygame.image.load('sprites/sprite1.png')
        image2 = pygame.image.load('sprites/sprite2.png')
        image3 = pygame.image.load('sprites/sprite3.png')
        while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                return

        screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
        screen.blit(image, (320, 240))
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    Game().main(screen)
```

I am looking to create a more dynamic image by changing the first sprite with the second and so on for at least three sprites possibly more  (as `sprite1.png`, `sprite2.png`, `sprite3.png`).  How can I cycle images after a given time interval has expired, for example: 1 second 1/2 seconds...

Comment: A separate loop that changes the sprite with, for example, 1 second sleep there as pause. Easiest achieved with threads!

Comment: Separate thread per image? Im confused as to where to use threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly more detail on @Puciek's suggestion in the comments, one could use a loop such as

```
import time

for img in [image, image1, image2]:
    screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
    screen.blit(img, (320, 240))
    time.sleep(1)    # sleep 1 second before continuing
```

Comment: You will definitly want that in separate thread, or at least a separate "rendering" thread that stays far away from main loop.

Comment: Yes, but that should be the basic construct of what goes inside the thread.

Comment: Well, I am suggesting a valid way to upgrade your answer to much more useful one!

Comment: I agree, but can't give away all the details!  Also, I've never really played with the `threading` module in python :-o.  Feel free to make your own, better answer :).

Comment: Way too lazy for that, that is why I stick to the comments section.

Comment: And yet you added an even more detailed answer than mine :-p.  Yours should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

Lets go there from the top, when writing a game it's very important to keep the rendering loop away from the main loop of your program (the one that handles window events). This way even when something will get stuck in your rendering process, your window will be much less likely to become unresponsive. Among other benefits, for example people will be able to resize, and otherwise manipulate it, without interrupting the graphics thread.
There are some nice tutorials for it around the web, and while I don't have one at hand for python, [SFML tutorials can teach you the right concepts](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/) which you can then use in python.

With that public service out of the way, when you already have the application split into separate threads, we are left with the issue of animations. Very simple implementation, and certainly not the best, would be to spawn a separate thread for each image that will cosist only of something like that:

```
def shake_it():
  while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    #do rotation here
```

While this will work quite well, it is clearly not the best solution because it's very non-flexible. Imagine that now you would also like to do something else periodically, for example make your NPCs patrol the fort. This will require another thread, and this would quickly escalate to quite a high number of threads (which isn't bad in itself, but not a desired effect).

So to the rescue would be a much more generic thread - event handler. A class that will control all your functions that need to be executed at specific intervals. And then, in that additional thread you would use for animating images, you would run an instance of event_handler in the loop instead, which would work as an abstract for actions like animation.

Answer (score -3):

To cycle through sprite images you should just blit the corresponding images in the loop. A good approach is to place all the images of the sequence in one image and load it when the program starts. Then use subsurface() function to get the image for blitting, so you can bind the "window" of the subsurface within the whole image with some variable which is changing in the loop. A separate question is, how to control the frequency, there are few approaches, here is one simple example of sprite animation. It is the same sprite sequence with 8 states, which is cycling at three different FPS: initial - 12 fps (1/12 second pause), then 1/3 of initial fps = 4 fps (3/12 second pause) and 1/12 of initial fps = 1 fps (12/12 = 1 second pause). I post the whole script, so you can run and see how it works, just put it with the image in one place and run the script.
Use this image with the script:

[image]

Source code:

```
import pygame, os
from pygame.locals import *

def Cycle(n, N) :           # n - current state, N - max number of states
    value = n+1 
    case1 = (value >= N) 
    case2 = (value < N)
    result = case1 * 0 + case2 * value
    return result

w = 600         # window size
h = 400
cdir = os.path.curdir       # current directory in terminal
states = 8      # number of sprite states

pygame.init()
DISP = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
BG = (36, 0, 36)        # background color
DISP.fill(BG)
band_1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(cdir, "band1.png")).convert()
K = 4           # global scale factor
band_1 = pygame.transform.scale(band_1, (K * band_1.get_width(), K * band_1.get_height()))
band_1.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
sw = K*8            # sprite width
sh = K*8            # sprite height
r0 = (100, 100, sw, sh)     # sprite 0 rectangle
r1 = (150, 100, sw, sh)     # sprite 1 rectangle
r2 = (200, 100, sw, sh)     # sprite 2 rectangle
s0 = 0          # initial state of sprite 0
s1 = 0          # initial state of sprite 1
s2 = 0          # initial state of sprite 2
t0 = 1          # main ticker
t1 = 1          # ticker 1
t2 = 1          # ticker 2
Loop_1 = True
FPS = 12
clock = pygame.time.Clock( ) 
while Loop_1 :
    clock.tick(FPS)
    DISP.fill(BG, r0)
    sprite_0 = band_1.subsurface((s0*sw, 0, sw, sh))
    DISP.blit(sprite_0, r0)
    s0 = Cycle(s0, states)
    if t1 == 3 :
        DISP.fill(BG, r1)
        sprite_1 = band_1.subsurface((s1*sw, 0, sw, sh))
        DISP.blit(sprite_1, r1)
        s1 = Cycle(s1, states)
        t1 = 0
    if t2 == 12 :
        DISP.fill(BG, r2)
        sprite_2 = band_1.subsurface((s2*sw, 0, sw, sh))
        DISP.blit(sprite_2, r2)
        s2 = Cycle(s2, states)
        t2 = 0
    for event in pygame.event.get( ):
        if event.type == QUIT : Loop_1 = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE : Loop_1 = False
#   t0 = t0 + 1 
    t1 = t1 + 1 
    t2 = t2 + 1 
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit( )
```

Comment: That is a lot of code which is barely readable, primarily because of variable names. Ironically you have a lot fo comments in simple variable assignments which don't need them (they just need proper names), but zero comments in the actual logic.

Comment: @Puciek If it is unreadable for you it doesn't mean it is unreadable for others. OP can always ask if it is not clear to some point. And how do you think threads will help at all for the a beginner just to make up simple animation? Furthermore I barely see any relation of this particular question to threads. Are you serious about creating threads for every animated character?

Comment: If you want to comment on my answer, feel free to comment under it, as this is where comments to it belong.

Comment: Okay, but from your comments I see you won't make a complete example anyway so what can I comment on? Off-topic: I don't know whether It was you down-voting, If yes please consider that it should be done if the example is false or not question-related. So it helps to filter the knowledgebase, and it doesn't bother me personally at all, just posted a simple working example here.

Comment: That actually is wrong. I downvoted it because the example provided is of extremely bad quality, and big chunk of your answer (and comments) consists of rants related to other answer, and is barely related to  answering the question.
If you think that my (and someone elses) down votes are not fair, feel free to report it to the moderator.

Comment: Oh I missed that part of your post! Answer doesn't have to include complete and working solution, it just have to answer the question. It sometimes involves working code, but that is not a requirement.

Comment: Ok, now I see, sorry for beeing inpolite in my answer. But in what way you find my code 'extremely bad quality'? That is really interesting :)  Probably it is just that all have their own habits of code writing.

Comment: We were all new here at some point, there is some learning curve to overcome ;). And after removing the unnecessary bit, is the biggest issue is the one i've mentioned above - the code sample presented is very confusing. If you were to refactor it, at the very least by changing variable names to something meaningful, and including comments where they are due (preferably also to break down the application into manageable functions instead of one large spaghetti string) I will most likely change my down vote to an up vote. You have to understand that you know what K is, we don't share your brain